# copy link into multiple subfolders

Tags: linux, unix, symlink, ln

I am looking if there is a simple use of ln program to create multiple symbolic links in multiple subdirectories all pointing to same file.

Example.

I'm in a directory **/home/user/workspace** and want to make a symbolic link of **/home/user/reference/table.csv** to several directories **/home/user/workspace/project1;/home/user/workspace/project2** etc. - basically to all subdirectories of workspace. (every project gets their own link to reference data)

The first hunch of **ln -s /home/user/reference/table.csv */** doesn't work.

I'm sure there are nice ways to accomplish it with piping some find etc. 
But it does SEEM like something that could maybe just be accomplished within ln program itself.

IS it possible? If not then all scripts/pipes etc. that allow me to do the same are welcome too.

Answer (score 2):

Options for `ln` are

```
ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
ln [OPTION]... TARGET                  (2nd form)
ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...  (4th form)
```

None of which matches what you described.

Writing a script may be what you want. Some thing like below.

```
for d in dir1 dir2 dir3
do
   ln -s /home/user/reference/table.csv  $d
done
```